# how to fix error when UWP referencing netstandard2.0

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-standard

I've created UWP App using C# and reference NetStandard 2.0 but when trying build and deploy I get following error 
[image: error]

I am using min version : 10.0.16299.0 that suppose to support NetStandard 2.0.
Anyone have any idea how to resolved it ?

Comment: What do you mean by "referenced" net standard 2.0? Did you reference a library or nuget package that is build using net standard 2?

Comment: I reference a library which is net standard 2.

Comment: Have you used some specific APIs in your library? Please check the APIs you use if they're available in UWP. [.NET API Browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/index?view=dotnet-uwp-10.0)